# certificate revocation list file size

Tags: certificates, crl

Crl files are growing linearly. I wonder with 10 revoked certificate, what is the storage size of crl file and so on. For every revoke certificate, how much increase the size of the crl?

Comment: Note that one reason for certificates to have expiration dates is to limit the size of CRLs...

Comment: @SEJPM I dont understand what you mean. I asked about what is the empty crl file? then when adding certificate to file how much size increase for crl file.  For 5 revoked certificate, what is the storage size of crl file? For 10 revoked certificate what is the storage size of crl file? Like that.

Comment: I know. This is why I commented and didn't answer. I indeed expect an answer to be as concrete as possible as to how big CRLs with $n$ certificates are.

Comment: This will depend on the CRL format. They store cert serial numbers, but PEM format is 4/3 the size of DER, and that's just for X.509. Other cert types wiul have different serial number sizes.

Comment: @SAI Peregrinus I am asking for X509 certificates as a crl file. And I want to know that corresponding verification cost time. It is growing linearly. But how can i compute verification cost when searching certificate from crl.